# error Using QTest Macro QCOMPARE

Tags: c++, qtestlib

I want use QTest  Macro QCOMPARE  in my code,but I receive errors.

QTestString.h

```
#ifndef QTESTSTRING_H
#define QTESTSTRING_H
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>


class TestqstringTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestqstringTest();

private slots:
    void testCase1();
};
#endif // QTESTSTRING_H
```

QTestString.cpp

```
#include "QTestString.h"

TestqstringTest::TestqstringTest()
{


    testCase1();
}

void TestqstringTest::testCase1()
{

     QString str = "Hello";


     QCOMPARE(str.toUpper(),(QString)"hELLO");


}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "QTestString.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);



    TestqstringTest *test = new TestqstringTest();


    return a.exec();
}
```

However, I receive the following  errors:

> ASSERT: "QTest::testLogger" in file qtestlog.cpp, line 266 The program
>   has unexpectedly finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,you must use `int QTest::qExec ( QObject * testObject, int argc = 0, char ** argv = 0 )` to excute it ,then the testlog output correctly.